# Accidentally moved several files into one file

Tags: windows, bash, find, mv

I sometimes use bash under Windows 10 to move files with find.
I wanted to move some files into a new folder. Every file is in it's own subfolder and I wanted to move all of these certain files into one new, so I ran this command:

```
find -type f -path "*files" -exec mv {} newFolder \;
```

But this command created a new file named newFolder which now seems to contain my files. I don't know why this happened, I thought that mv moves into directories.

If someone knows how to get my files out of this file I would be very happy :)

Comment: I'm afraid all but the last file are gone, because you executed `mv` _once per input file_, due to using `\;` rather than `+` as the `-exec` terminatior.  File `newFolder` is now effectively the _last_ input file _only_. To avoid this problem in the future, add a trailing `/` to the target path: `mv {} newFolder/` - this ensures that `newFolder` is treated as a directory - and fails if it doesn't exist. As an aside: [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) is a better fit for your question.

Comment: Oh that's bad, seems like I destroyed my files :( But thanks for your fast answer. You're right I should've posted this on superuser but I paniced and didn't really think :D

Comment: Also its a lot safer to explicitly specify a path value for `find` to operate on. (The version you use must have a default path value for the command you posted to work.)

Comment: @Zlemini: GNU `find` defaults to `.` (the current dir).

Comment: @mklement0 ahh that explains it, thanks.

Comment: Also, when doing mass moves like this, you should **always** use `mv -i`, which will ask for confirmation before overwriting files. You will make mistakes, the `-i` flag provides a safety net.